# Maven Dependency Netty - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, maven, netty, activemq-artemis

I have an Java Spring application war file connecting to JMS queues in JBoss EAP 7.0. Artemis

Once I send the message log is showing the follow message:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.internal.ObjectUtil.checkPositiveOrZero(ILjava/lang/String;)I`

My investigation point me to the Maven dependcy. Some articles mention could be a duplicate jar for Netty. I ran the `maven dependency:tree` to check, seems to me there is not duplicate jars

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------< com.cts.t24.transaction.screening:middleware >------------
[INFO] Building middleware 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ middleware ---
[INFO] com.cts.t24.transaction.screening:middleware:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:5.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-client:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.activemq:artemis-selector:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.jms:javax.jms-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.json:javax.json-api:jar:1.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-server:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq:artemis-core-client:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jgroups:jgroups:jar:3.6.13.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.johnzon:johnzon-core:jar:1.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.39.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.39.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.39.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.39.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.39.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.39.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.39.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.39.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.39.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.39.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq:artemis-server:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logmanager:jboss-logmanager:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:artemis-jdbc-store:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:artemis-native:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq:artemis-journal:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq:artemis-commons:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq:artemis-service-extensions:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_2.0_spec:jar:1.0-alpha-2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.26:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.26:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.26:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.28:compile
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.16:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.16:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.10.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.3:test
[INFO] \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.891 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-10T17:23:18-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.39.Final:compile contains the class of the method is looking for

```java
    public static int checkPositiveOrZero(int i, String name) {
        if (i < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + ": " + i + " (expected: >= 0)");
        }
        return i;
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the given argument is positive or zero. If it is not, throws {@link IllegalArgumentException}.
     * Otherwise, returns the argument.
     */
    public static long checkPositiveOrZero(long i, String name) {
        if (i < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + ": " + i + " (expected: >= 0)");
        }
        return i;
    }
```

As my understand by the log is being called by:WriteBufferWaterMark class contained by 
netty-transport:jar:4.1.39.Final:compile.

```java
    /**
     * This constructor is needed to keep backward-compatibility.
     */
    WriteBufferWaterMark(int low, int high, boolean validate) {
        if (validate) {
            checkPositiveOrZero(low, "low");
            if (high < low) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "write buffer's high water mark cannot be less than " +
                                " low water mark (" + low + "): " +
                                high);
            }
        }
        this.low = low;
        this.high = high;
    }
```

To me seems the class are compatibles but my concern is the log show `checkPositiveOrZero(ILjava/lang/String;)I` . It's like it is expecting an array of `String`. I am not an expert in Maven dependencies please any ideas why the `NoSuchMethodError`, will appreciate.

Full log:

```
2019-10-10 17:56:28,526 INFO  [com.cts.t24.transaction.screening.controller.TestConnectionLegacyR] (default task-1) Attempting to acquire connection factory "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"
2019-10-10 17:56:29,041 INFO  [com.cts.t24.transaction.screening.controller.TestConnectionLegacyR] (default task-1) Found connection factory "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" in JNDI
2019-10-10 17:56:29,041 INFO  [com.cts.t24.transaction.screening.controller.TestConnectionLegacyR] (default task-1) Attempting to acquire destination "jms/queue/requestQueue"
2019-10-10 17:56:29,119 INFO  [com.cts.t24.transaction.screening.controller.TestConnectionLegacyR] (default task-1) Found destination "jms/queue/requestQueue" in JNDI
2019-10-10 17:56:29,151 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2019-10-10 17:56:29.151 DEBUG 4112 --- [ default task-1] io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector       : -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
2019-10-10 17:56:29,151 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2019-10-10 17:56:29.151 DEBUG 4112 --- [ default task-1] io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector       : -Dio.netty.leakDetection.maxRecords: 4
2019-10-10 17:56:29,166 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2019-10-10 17:56:29.166 DEBUG 4112 --- [ default task-1] i.n.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup    : -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 8
2019-10-10 17:56:29,182 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2019-10-10 17:56:29.182 DEBUG 4112 --- [ default task-1] io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop        : -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
2019-10-10 17:56:29,182 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2019-10-10 17:56:29.182 DEBUG 4112 --- [ default task-1] io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop        : -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) ERROR 2019-10-10 17:56:29 org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/testReq] due to exception [io.netty.util.internal.ObjectUtil.checkPositiveOrZero(ILjava/lang/String;)I]
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.internal.ObjectUtil.checkPositiveOrZero(ILjava/lang/String;)I
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.netty.channel.WriteBufferWaterMark.<init>(WriteBufferWaterMark.java:59)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.netty.channel.WriteBufferWaterMark.<init>(WriteBufferWaterMark.java:51)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.start(NettyConnector.java:490)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.openTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1045)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1096)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.establishNewConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1307)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:902)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionWithRetry(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:798)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.connect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:241)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:782)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:844)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createContext(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:304)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createContext(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:297)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at com.cts.t24.transaction.screening.controller.TestConnectionLegacyR.TestConnect(TestConnectionLegacyR.java:61)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at com.cts.t24.transaction.screening.controller.TransactionController.testRequestQueue(TransactionController.java:33)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,229 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:792)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2019-10-10 17:56:29,244 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there another netty jar that is included in JBoss distribution which is used instead of one used for your app development.

According to https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673 - there should be version 4.0.35.Final, but ObjectUtil class appeared only in 4.1.0.Beta4-SNAPSHOT (according to this commit https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/04f77b76f802a5bb30447eb0e3580f6ba0e1f2db#diff-3898ecbaeae93ec4a50462f60da1840b)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clue Woworks, my problem: i was putting directly, jboss-client.jar in the project this cause a conflict with my dependencies, since the jboss client have the same classes as artemis dependencies for Netty (different versions).